# How to use try/catch with playwright page with click() and using timeout

Tags: javascript, playwright

I'm quite new to JS.

I have this code:

```js
async function downloadOriginalFile(page, scanData, delay = 10000) {
  const { url, zipFname, caseId, scanId } = scanData;
  await page.goto(url);
  if (page.url().includes('/sign_in')) {
    console.log('Not logged in');
    throw new Error('Login failed');
  } else {
    console.log(`/${caseId}/${scanId} => Opened Scan Page`);
  }

  await page.waitForTimeout(delay);
  const page4Promise = page.waitForEvent('popup');
  const download2Promise = page.waitForEvent('download');

  // lines in question:
  await page.getByRole('main').getByRole('link').first().click(); // multi-grader
  await page.locator('div:nth-child(6) > a').waitForTimeout().click(); // solo grader

  const download = await download2Promise;
  console.log(`/${scanData.caseId}/${scanData.scanId} => Downloading original file`);
  await page.waitForTimeout(delay);

  await download.saveAs(path.join(path.dirname(zipFname), caseId, scanId, 'original_file', download.suggestedFilename()));
  // wait for the download and delete the temporary file
  await download.delete();
}
```

My problem is that I can only have one of those:

```js
  await page.getByRole('main').getByRole('link').first().click(); // multi-grader
  // or
  await page.locator('div:nth-child(6) > a').waitForTimeout().click(); // solo grader
```

depending on the page was loaded.
I'd like to use somehow try/catch with timeout to test whatever the two works after, say, 3 s. But I'm open to suggestions as well.

**UPDATE**:
Based on @Ermi answer, I was able to better troubleshot my problem.

I found out that
`await page.getByRole('main').getByRole('link').first().click(); // multi-grader`
will also show up in `solo-grader` page, so I reverse the order.

Also, I should originally have used:

```js
await page.locator('div:nth-child(6) > a').click(); // solo-grader`
```

This is what works if I load solo-grader page, even with `page.getByRole('main')...` there.

**updated code:**

```js
async function downloadOriginalFile(page, scanData, delay = 10000) {
  const { url, zipFname, caseId, scanId } = scanData;
  await page.goto(url);
  if (page.url().includes('/sign_in')) {
    console.log('Not logged in');
    throw new Error('Login failed');
  } else {
    console.log(`/${caseId}/${scanId} => Opened Scan Page`);
  }

  await page.waitForTimeout(delay);
  const page4Promise = page.waitForEvent('popup');
  const download2Promise = page.waitForEvent('download');

  let download;
  try {
    // Try solo-grader
    await page.waitForTimeout(delay).locator('div:nth-child(6) > a').click(); // solo-grader
    console.log(`/${caseId}/${scanId} => Clicked on solo-grader link`);
    download = await download2Promise;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Failed to click on solo-grader link: ${error.message}`);
    try {
      // Try multi-grader
      await page.getByRole('main').getByRole('link').first().click(); // multi-grader
      console.log(`/${caseId}/${scanId} => Clicked on multi-grader link`);
      download = await download2Promise;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Failed to click on multi-grader link: ${error.message}`);
      throw new Error('Failed to download original file');
    }
  }

  console.log(`/${caseId}/${scanId} => Downloading original file`);
  await page.waitForTimeout(delay);

  await download.saveAs(path.join(path.dirname(zipFname), caseId, scanId, 'original_file', download.suggestedFilename()));
  // Wait for the download and delete the temporary file
  await download.delete();
}
```

However, this line:
`await page.waitForTimeout(delay).locator('div:nth-child(6) > a').click(); // solo-grader`
fails with:

```
Failed to click on solo grader link: page.waitForTimeout(...).locator is not a function
```

So basically, I want to try:

```js
await page.locator('div:nth-child(6) > a').click(); // solo-grader`
```

for 10000 ms or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`waitForTimeout` is used to wait for a certain amount of time, and locator is used to locate elements on the page. They are separate functions and should not be chained together like that.

You can achieve it using only `{ timeout }` as the following:

```
let download;
try {
  // Try solo-grader
  const soloGraderLink = await page.locator('div:nth-child(6) > a');
  await soloGraderLink.click({ timeout: delay / 5 }); // solo-grader with timeout
  console.log(`/${caseId}/${scanId} => Clicked on solo-grader link`);
  download = await download2Promise;
} catch (error) {
  console.log(`Failed to click on solo-grader link: ${error.message}`);
  try {
    // Try multi-grader
    await page.getByRole('main').getByRole('link').first().click(); // multi-grader
    console.log(`/${caseId}/${scanId} => Clicked on multi-grader link`);
    download = await download2Promise;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Failed to click on multi-grader link: ${error.message}`);
    throw new Error('Failed to download original file');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, please see my update in the main thread.

Comment: Based on the updated code, i have also updated my answer.

Comment: I got it to work when I did `await page.locator('div:nth-child(6) > a').click({ timeout: delay / 5 });` and I didn't even need the line `await page.waitForTimeout(10000); // Wait for 10 seconds` anymore.

Comment: Great to hear that you got it to work! Using the `{ timeout }` option directly in the click function is indeed another approach to handle timeouts for individual actions.

Comment: if you update your answer I can accept it

Comment: I have updated it now!